# R - How to convert values within data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame (see picture for extract) with indices for different sectors. Each row is a month the index of the specific sector stands for. But instead of the indices I need to work with relative returns - means -> ln (Index of month t / Index of month t-1). How is it possible to transfer the table I got into a table containing the relative returns? e.g. Row 2 = ln (Row 2/Row 1) etc.

Any help is welcome!

[Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHhQl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n <- nrow(df)
returns = apply(df, 2, function(x) log(x[-1]/x[-n]))
```

## Data

```
df = structure(list(TOTXTER = c(2215.83, 2245.72, 2270.89, 2223.7, 
2424.06, 2474.17, 2588.63, 2524.26, 2538.74, 2729.11, 2544.33
), OILGSER = c(4674.38, 4676.73, 4637.56, 4573.83, 4983.08, 5244.84, 
5449.16, 5301.82, 5637.56, 5941.14, 5485.61), BMATRER = c(1660.95, 
1671.76, 1693.66, 1635.54, 1720.29, 1760.02, 1785.75, 1789.98, 
1789.09, 1887.73, 1716.61), CHMCLER = c(2103.37, 2105.47, 2108.5, 
2020.08, 2086.4, 2133.43, 2202.96, 2177.63, 2142.27, 2274.55, 
2108.15), BRESRER = c(1130.31, 1112.28, 1163.64, 1129.64, 1218.04, 
1262.35, 1271.25, 1296.26, 1280.15, 1331.12, 1110.19), INDUSER = c(1849.7, 
1847.57, 1858.19, 1820.16, 1963.64, 1986.84, 2026.37, 2053.58, 
2036.51, 2185.57, 1959.43), CNSTMER = c(1649.65, 1686.22, 1715.39, 
1670.04, 1774.8, 1808.93, 1786.93, 1799.99, 1844.09, 1928.18, 
1786.66), INDGSER = c(1823.64, 1820.19, 1830.12, 1787.6, 1925.63, 
1956.93, 1999.76, 2018.36, 2018.68, 2164.85, 1967.47), RITDVER = c(1073.32, 
1126.17, 1130.85, 1095.9, 1117.03, 1083.76, 1139.1, 1100.51, 
1120.35, 1138.33, 1125.28)), .Names = c("TOTXTER", "OILGSER", 
"BMATRER", "CHMCLER", "BRESRER", "INDUSER", "CNSTMER", "INDGSER", 
"RITDVER"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But I always receive the error note: dim(X) must have a positive length

Comment: You are using df data or something different?

Comment: My actual data frame contains 240 rows for each of the 30 columns. I'm not sure how to apply your solution on my data frame! Sorry, I'm quite new to this!

Comment: This solution works if your data stored in dataframe called "df". Probably you importing your data to R using df = read.table() or df = read.csv() so the solution should work.

Comment: Works perfect! Tried to find a solution for days! If ever in Hamburg, always welcome for a beer ;-)